# Health Data is suddenly using a lot of iCloud Storage on iOS 10

Tags: ios, icloud, health.app

I've noticed that since I've upgraded to iOS 10 public beta, Health Data is using 275mb of my iCloud storage (and it's increasing), which I think is much more than usual.

As far as I can recall, it was less than 10mb on iOS 9. Any ideas on why it's eating up iCloud storage and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what else you can do about it, except don't back it up. This really feels like a bug/optimization problem on Apple's side. 
Mine is 655MB and I'm pretty sure it was ~500 just a week or two ago.